# Cannot connect to second docker container - port error

Tags: docker, containers

I have two directories each running an identical docker build except for the allocated ports. I cannot connect to one of the containers in my localhost.

After running the docker ps command I see that `80/tcp` being prepended to my second `recipe-blog` container. Below is my yml file, its nothing crazy, just setting up a database running php my admin and have it connect to a WordPress install. I also attached an image of the `docker ps` command.

```
services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # phpmyadmin
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '9090:90'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password 
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:5.3.0
    ports:
      - '9000:90'
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data: {}
  wp-content:
```

[image: docker ps command]

Once again `- finalsandbox_ I` can connect to fine, I cannot connect to `recipe-blog_`. The only difference between the two yml files is that for the `recipe-blog_` I changed the ports to be `9090:90` instead of `8080:80` and `9000:90` instead of `8000:80`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to access to phpmyadmin dashboard? if yes, according to dockerhub the port exposed should be 80 (https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/) please link it. 
Example:
```
phpmyadmin:  ports:
      - '9090:80'
```
you can now reach it on port 9090. http://localhost:9090

Comment: same as wordpress change 90 to 80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me, example

```
version: "3"
services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # phpmyadmin
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '9090:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress 
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:5.3.0
    ports:
      - '9000:80'
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data: {}
  wp-content:
```

Change all the ports assigned by 90 to 80.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

with your we-browser favorite, connect to http://127.0.0.1:9000 and http://127.0.0.1:9090

Comment: AHA that gets me a step closer. I can now connect to the ports, but the WordPress port gives me a "Error establishing a database connection" and when I try to log into phpmyadmin using username: wordpress and password: wordpress I get an access denied error. I wonder why that is since im using the same username/password as what is in the yml file.

Comment: use user:root instead

Comment: No luck. I think there might be something wrong with my local php.

Comment: user: root
pass: wordpress

Comment: No, nothing. For whatever reason my WP cannot connect to the DB on this container.

Comment: can you add  '''WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress'' below wordpress environment and rebuild it with --build

Comment: Same issue. phpmyadmin works fine on my other container. Could it be that two containers cant run phpmyadmin at the same time?

Comment: If they are no network/port conflict on your stack, it will should be okay, but why did you have two phpmyadmin?

Comment: I have a separate container running the same docker build. Everything identical except for the ports.